# Is there a way to get both Sneaky Bastard aced and Bulletproof aced?

Tags: payday-2

I'm having trouble finding the points, especially since I'm not currently infamied enough to have point requirements lowered. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven't played in a while so I forget the point requirements for top-tier skills, but you should have 120 skill points at level 100. Is it 52 skill points minimum to ace a top tier skill? If so you can clear 2 paths, but you'll only have 18 skill points spare. Infamy cost reductions allow you to build more optimally (i.e. not waste as many points as a prerequisite to take the skills you want).

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep this in mind. If I have enough points like you say then I should be able to figure it out.

Comment: You could ace both if you wanted, but I wouldn't recommend it. Have you considered an Enforcer/Fugitive build instead? Technician/Fugitive is a niche build involving an LBV Crook or Grinder, but it's not very effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all going to depend on your own level, but it is possible.  If you're level 100 (and not infamous) I believe you should be able to get it, however it was a long time ago when I wasn't infamous.

Here is an example of what you can do to get there, please note this isn't optimal, as it doens't take into account a lot of soft skills (ones that you should pretty much always have), but it'll give you an idea:

**Technical Tree**

- Unlocking The Technician - Basic
- Demolition Man - Basic
- Rifleman - Aced
- Sharpshooter - Aced
- Combat Engineer - Basic
- Hardware Expert - Aced
- Drill Sergeant - Aced
- Sentry Gun - Basic
- Jack of All Trades - Aced
- Shaped Charge - Aced
- Bulletproof - Aced

**Fugitive Tree**

- Unlocking the Fugitive - Basic
- Daredevil - Aced
- Thick Skin - Aced
- Duck and Cover - Aced
- Run and Gun - Aced
- Quick Fix - Aced
- Uppers - Aced
- Low Blow - Aced
- Sneaky Bastard - Aced

I created this uysing PD2Skills: 
http://pd2skills.com/#/v3/tSOLhJEGBcDa:fROMJEGBDa:::

From a personal stand point, I don't think you'd really want Bulletproof & Sneaky Bastard, as with Dodge you want to maximise your dodge with Mastermind / Ghost skills, as with max dodge you won't get hit a lot.

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably use this guide. I know it's not the most effective build but I like trying weird stuff.

Comment: No problem. If its helped please mark this as answer, then it will close the thread off.